# renewcommand within newenvironment

Tags: pdftex, environments

I have a problem with redefining a comamnd within a new environment.

Not working MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysection@star}{\mysection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\mysection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\mysubsection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\subsection*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysubsection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\subsection{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{MySubAppendix}{%
    \makeatletter%
    \renewcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}%
    \makeatother%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{MySubAppendix}
\mysection{Sub After Block Example}
\end{MySubAppendix}
\end{document}
```

This leads, with pdflatex, to:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo")) (refman.aux)
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor
                 \@m {}
l.19 \mysection
               {Sub After Block Example}
```

Working MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysection@star}{\mysection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\mysection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\mysubsection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\subsection*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysubsection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\subsection{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{MySubAppendix}{%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{MySubAppendix}
    \makeatletter%
    \renewcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}%
    \makeatother%
\mysection{Sub After Block Example}
\end{MySubAppendix}
\end{document}
```

At first glance the working version would be an alternative, but when having this multiple times it is a bit of a problem writing each times the part:

```
    \makeatletter%
    \renewcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}%
    \makeatother%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use the pair `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` in the expansion code of a macro. I once asked a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333839/82917). (Similar but not quite a duplicate.)

Comment: @campa It *is* a duplicate: whether `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment` are involved is the same.

Comment: @egreg In my old question the `@` was part of the _argument_, while here it is explicitly present in the replacement text: that's why I deemed the questions similar but not exact duplicates. But of course the underlying problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by @campa I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysection@star}{\mysection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\mysection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\mysubsection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\subsection*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\mysubsection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\subsection{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\makeatletter%
\newenvironment{MySubAppendix}{%
    \renewcommand{\mysection}{\@ifstar{\mysubsection@star}{\mysubsection@nostar}}%
}{}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\begin{MySubAppendix}
\mysection{Sub After Block Example}
\end{MySubAppendix}
\end{document}
```

and this is working in this small example but also in my larger code.

Comment: @egreg is the chosen solution in the answer a correct solution or is there a better way?