# Inserting a command in a def causes a bug

Tags: geometry, crop, def

When I execute the following command, it works:

```
\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother
```

But, when I include this command in a `\def`, as shown below, it no longer works:

```
\def\fixCroppingBugCausedByChangeOfGeometry
{\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother}
```

How to fix that?

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[
  width=25truecm, height=32truecm, cam, 
  pdftex,
  center
]{crop}


\def\fixCroppingBugCausedByChangeOfGeometry
{\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother}


\begin{document}

Page 1

\newpage
\newgeometry{left = 5cm, right = 5cm}
\fixCroppingBugCausedByChangeOfGeometry
%\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother

Page 2

\newpage
\restoregeometry
\fixCroppingBugCausedByChangeOfGeometry
%\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother

Page 3

\end{document}
```

---

PS:
I have to do that because I want to execute the command `\CROP@center` only if the `crop` package is loaded.

Comment: the \makeatletter must be outside of the definition `\makeatletter\def\fixCroppingBugCausedByChangeOfGeometry{\CROP@center}\makeatother`

Comment: As a newbie I had a similar problem ;-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333839/82917